# CSS/HTML - разметка внутри всплывающей подсказки

Tags: html, css

Есть вот такой дизайн. Он сейчас в проекте и все работает, но я подумал что хотел бы поменять макет и соответственно сделать так что бы в тултипе картинка была слева от текста.
Уже три дня мучаюсь, но так ничего и не получается. Помогите пожалуйста!

```js
function getCoords(elem) {
  let box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();

  return {
    top: box.top + window.pageYOffset,
    right: box.right + window.pageXOffset,
    bottom: box.bottom + window.pageYOffset,
    left: box.left + window.pageXOffset
  };
}

let textAndTooltip = document.getElementsByClassName('textAndTooltip');
let tooltip = document.getElementsByClassName('tooltip');
let tooltipPositionOk = [];

for (let i = 0; i < textAndTooltip.length; i++) {
  tooltipPositionOk[i] = false;

  textAndTooltip[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    newPositionTooltip(i);
  });
}

function newPositionTooltip(i) {
  if (!tooltipPositionOk[i]) {
    tooltipPositionOk[i] = true;
  } else {
    return;
  }

  tooltip[i].classList.remove('tooltip_left', 'tooltip_right');

  console.log(tooltip[i]);

  if (getCoords(tooltip[i]).left < 0) {
    tooltip[i].classList.add('tooltip_left');
  } else if (getCoords(tooltip[i]).right > document.documentElement.clientWidth) {
    tooltip[i].classList.add('tooltip_right');

  }
}

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < textAndTooltip.length; i++) {
    tooltipPositionOk[i] = false;
  }
});
```

```css
.textAndTooltip {
  position: relative;
}

.textAndTooltip__tooltip {
  display: none;
}

.textAndTooltip__text {
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.textAndTooltip__text:hover+.textAndTooltip__tooltip {
  display: block;
  animation: UpToDown .6s ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.textAndTooltip__tooltip:hover {
  display: block;
  animation: UpToDown .6s ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes UpToDown {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 1em;
  }
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  max-width: 300px;
  min-width: 200px;
  background-color: #3989c9;
  padding: .5em;
  aling-content: left;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: white;
  z-index: 2;
}

.tooltip_right {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.tooltip_left {
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Online HTML Editor</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    <span class="textAndTooltip">
            <strong class="textAndTooltip__text">
            Point ME!.
        </strong>
        <span class="textAndTooltip__tooltip tooltip">
        <span><a style='align-content:left; text-align:left;'class="tooltip__img" href="https://clck.ru/J36a7" target="_blank">
                <img src="https://inlnk.ru/1PnAYw" alt="babababa" width="100%">
            </a></span>
    <span class="tooltip__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque rem tempora cum impedit commodi. Voluptas accusantium recusandae dolores, officia quasi.</span></span>
    </span>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Было бы прикольно, если бы мы видели, что вы хотите сделать. Или хотя-бы, как у вас сейчас есть.

Comment: `<img src="https://inlnk.ru/1PnAYw" alt="babababa" width="100%" style='float: left;'/>` попробуй так

Comment: @Daniil Посмотрите сноски на википедии при наведении на активные ссылки

Comment: @puffleeck попробовал, не сработало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте при показе свойство display: inline-flex; (или любое другое инлайновое). Оно отобазить картинку слева в Вашем случае. Остается только поиграться с размерами изображения и текста

```css
.textAndTooltip__text:hover+.textAndTooltip__tooltip {
  display: inline-flex;
  animation: UpToDown .6s ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам, добрый господин) Все получилось!) 

А есть какая-нибудь возможность отрегулировать по высоте что бы картинка была по середине от высоты?